# Ignite Caches are not loading from Cassandra

Tags: java, caching, cassandra, persistence, ignite

I am using Ignite with cassandra as a persistent store. putting records in ignite cache is stored well in cassandra.
When I start Ignite, and when the lifecycle event "After Node Starts" is triggerd, I run the following code

```
l1CoreCache.loadCache(null);
l1LookupCache.loadCache(null);
System.out.println(l1CoreCache.size(CachePeekMode.ONHEAP));
System.out.println(l1CoreCache.size(CachePeekMode.OFFHEAP));
System.out.println(l1LookupCache.size(CachePeekMode.ONHEAP));
System.out.println(l1LookupCache.size(CachePeekMode.OFFHEAP));
```

I get zeroes in all the print statements. I tried to perform some queries and I get EMPTY result sets. the records are retrieved only if used the cache.get() method using specific ID ?!!

I want to load all the caches on starting .... any help please?

Comment: Try to experiment with custom Cassandra query, like: `l1CoreCache.loadCache(null, "select * from table_space.table limit 3")` and/or enable query tracing on Cassandra server if there are valid requests.

Comment: @Mitya Xmitya thanks a lot. It helped 
But I have another question. What is wrong with loading without a query? as this is mentioned in Ignite Documentation

Comment: I just supposed that there might be something wrong with query that Ignite generates for Cassandra (`"select * from " + controller.getPersistenceSettings().getKeyspace() + "." + cassandraTable() + ";"`), or there may be some Cassandra limits. You can check Cassandra's logs if there errors on executing that request.